# Are NavigationTiming properties available in UserTiming measure?

Tags: html, w3c, navigation-timing-api

Is it possible to use the NavigationTiming properties when using `measure` in the UserTiming API?

In other words, is the following according to spec?

```
window.performance.mark('foo');
window.performance.measure('myMeasurement', 'fetchStart', 'foo');
```

The [UserTiming spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/user-timing/#dom-performance-measure) states that the NavigationTiming properties are reserved when calling `mark`, and it seems to behave that way when I experiment in the console.

However, I can't find anything in the spec which states this is the expected behavior. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/user-timing/#dom-performance-measure):

> May be the name of one of the attributes in the PerformanceTiming interface [Navigation Timing].